# Django Updating Mode; 2 arguments needed 1given

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to create a form that will update one specific field in my Model, but I'm apparently passing too many arguments. I think I need all of them, so I don't know where the mistake is.

Thanks in advance for your help.

HTML

```
<div class=assessment_container>
     <div id=over>
         <label class=labels>Results:</label>
          <form action= "{% url 'Project:new_entry' %}"  method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
              <textarea name="result"</textarea>
              <input class="save" type="submit" value="Save">
          </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Urls.py

```
  url(r'^new_entry$', views.new_entry, name = "new_entry")
```

Views.py

```
def new_entry(request, tableA_id):
new = tableA.objects.edit('TableA_id', 
request.POST)
return redirect('/')
```

Models.py

```
class TableAManager(models.Manager):
    def edit(self, TableA_id, postData):
         answer = TableA.objects.get(id=TableA_id)
         answer.result = postData["result"]
         answer.save()


class TableA(models.Model):
first_cat = models.CharField(max_length=50)
result = models.TextField()
def __str__(self):
    return str (self.first_cat)
objects = TableAManager()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url(r'^new_entry/(?P<tableA_id>\d+)/$', views.new_entry, name = "new_entry")
```

in your html

```
<form action= "{% url 'Project:new_entry' tableA_id=some_id  %}"  method="POST">
```

change your url to this

Comment: Thanks. But now I'm getting: "NoReverseMatch at /Project/page/4
Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'Project/new_entry/(?P<TableA_id>\\d+)/$']"

Comment: What should "some_id" be? I'm getting: "NoReverseMatch at /Project/page/4
Reverse for 'new_entry' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'TableA_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'Project/new_entry/(?P<TableA_id>\\d+)/$']

Comment: that you have to know, because the function edit needs and id and which needs to be passed through the url to the view function